# Eclipse RCP - Calling image from AbstractUIPlugin.getImageDescriptor and ImageRegistry

Tags: eclipse, plugins, rcp

What is the different between calling image using `AbstractUIPlugin.getImageDescriptor` and putting an image into the image registry and calling from the image registry?

Seems like both are doing the same job. The first one is easier (less line of code!).

This code:

```
ImageDescriptor id = Activator.getImageDescriptor("image/image.png");
Image image = id.createImage();
```

vs

Putting into an image registry first..

```
protected void initializeImageRegistry(ImageRegistry registry) {
    super.initializeImageRegistry(registry);
    Bundle bundle = Platform.getBundle(ID);

    ImageDescriptor myImage = ImageDescriptor.createFromURL(
          FileLocator.find(bundle,
                           new Path("image/image.png"),
                                    null));
    registry.put(MY_IMAGE_ID, myImage);
}
```

then calling image from image registry..

```
AbstractUIPlugin plugin = Activator.getDefault();
ImageRegistry imageRegistry = plugin.getImageRegistry();
Image myImage = imageRegistry.get(Activator.MY_IMAGE_ID);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It creates separate images each time you invoke it. Finally you will end up with "No more handles" exception. :)

```
 ImageDescriptor id = Activator.getImageDescriptor("image/image.png");
    Image image = id.createImage();
```

Always cache images, reuse and dispose when you close your app. If you use `ImageRegistry`, `AbstractUIPlugin` will do the job of disposing it for you.

Comment: I will be saying this image as a background image. Will only be using it once for the whole life cycle. So this way should be easier and fine right?

Comment: I always suggest you to cache resources and reuse unless you have memory constraint